# Lifecycle of JobQueue with respect to callback method

Tags: java, android, multithreading, amazon-s3, android-priority-jobqueue

I am using `com.birbit:android-priority-jobqueue:1.3.5` to send data to server. Here is how.

```
@Override
public void onRun() throws Throwable {
  MyStuff myStuff = getMyStuffFromContentProvider(mDbId);
  SendAfterPhotosCallback callback = new SendAfterPhotosCallback() {…}
  callback.xDone=false;
  callback.yDone=false;
  callback.zDone=false;
  sendPhotosXToAmazonS3UsingTransferUtility(myStuff,callback);
  sendPhotosYToAmazonS3UsingTransferUtility(myStuff,callback);
  sendPhotosZToAmazonS3UsingTransferUtility(myStuff,callback);
  //callback.sendJson(myStuff);
}
```

What’s the big deal? `sendJson` must be called after the other three methods are done with their work. But TransferUtility sends data to S3 asynchronously. So to track that each of these `-ToAmazonS3UsingTransferUtility` is successful I am using an AtomicInteger to count the completion of each `TransferObserver`.

```
public static abstract class SendAfterPhotosCallback{
        static boolean xDone = false;
        static boolean yDone = false;
        static boolean zDone = false;
        abstract public void sendJson(MyStuff myStuff)  throws Throwable;
    }
```

When each `-ToAmazonS3UsingTransferUtility` is completely done, it sets its respective flag to true (i.e. `callback.xDone=true`) and then calls `callback.sendJson(myStuff)`. Inside `sendJson` I check if all the flags are set to then send the json to server.

Anyway, since each `-ToAmazonS3UsingTransferUtility` will call `callback.sendJson(myStuff)` asynchronously, what happens if `callback.sendJson(myStuff)` throws an exception? Will `onRun()` of the job queue see it?

This is important because when `onRun` throws an exception the JobQueue knows to retry later.

To the best of my knowledge `onRun` is done running when the async calls are made. So how do I fix this problem so the code works well? Is there a way to get TransferUtility to work synchronously perhaps?